# ODBC header file location

Tags: odbc, datastage

I am trying to find odbc.h header file in datastage. When I googled it i came up with below command

$INCLUDE UNIVERSE.INCLUDE ODBC.H

Can anyone explain me what UNIVERSE.INCLUDE is? I could not find any folder name UNIVERSE in Datastage directories.